# Swift. Cannot convert value of type <T> to expected argument type <_>

Tags: ios, swift, generics

```
func arrayRequest<T>(request: Request<T>, callback: ((result: Results<T>) -> ())) {
    let parseOperation = buildRequest(request)
    parseOperation.completionBlock = {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            guard let parsedObject = parseOperation.results else {
                callback(result: Results.Failure(Error.RequestError))
                return
            }
            let results = Results.Success(parsedObject)
            callback(result: callback(result: results)) //Error
        })
    }
}
```

I have error:
Cannot convert value of type 'Results < T >' to expected argument type 'Results<_>'

```
enum Results<T> {
    case Failure(Error)
    case Success([T]) }
```

Comment: You've nested your callback in itself... I think you mean `callback(result: results)`

Comment: @originaluser2 Thanks. It was stupid question.